# Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 the navbar is showing lot of white space after collapsing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2, my page has navbar that gets responsive and get collapsed when it is opened in a small devices or the browser window size is lowered.

How ever it is causing about 60px padding between the top of the browser and collapsed navbar.

When I inspect in firebug i notice the body tag getting a style element from core.css
padding-top:60px;

this is causing the collapsed navbar to go down creating a white space at top for 60px, i could overide the style attribute, but thought of asking here if any one noticed this behavior and if the style overiding is the right solution for this?

Comment: Yeah, override it or comment it out as I said below.

Comment: @AliGajani that resolved the issue, just waiting to see alternative opinions

Comment: what is `core.css`? isn't bootstrap CSS named `bootstrap.css`?

Comment: @koala_dev yes my bad, i got a theme that was based on Bootstrap so i thought it was part of Bootstrap, but upon your comment when i revisit, it is actually added by theme developer, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Then I guess you can just remove the line as it has been proposed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just comment out that line of code. Venkat, it is absolutely a common issue, and you can simply override it. Go for it. However, I do recommend playing around with the core CSS of Bootstrap.

Comment: It turned out not a Bootstrap issue, but @Ali Gajani solution to remove the style works.